# python gnupg cannot user keychain keys

Tags: python, gpg

I have an issue using the gnupg module in python in Ubuntu 14.

My keychain is set up correctly. I can use gpg on the command line to decrypt files with having to enter my passphrase.

I have also checked that my gpg-agent is running.

However, in my python script, I constantly get an error to the effect that no passphrase is available for my private key, which it needs to decrypt the file.

The error I am getting is:

```
Error opening terminal: unknown
```

I have also confirmed that I am using GPG 2+

Code is:

```
import gnupg
import os

def set_auth(k):

    h = os.path.expanduser("~")

    gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='~/.gnupg',use_agent=True)

    with open(h + "/.secure/" + k + ".gpg", "rb") as f:
        status = gpg.decrypt_file(f, output=h + "/.secure/key.tmp")
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in the version of python that this issue of Ubuntu was installing.